# Обновление части кода

Tags: php

У меня есть кусок кода PHP (со строчки 25 по строчку 50) и мне надо, чтобы при определенных действиях этот код обновился, только этот код, а не полностью страница. Как это можно организовать?

Comment: **Что еще за:**

    (со строчки 25 по строчку 50)

В морской бой играете что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причём тут PHP, если надо обновить кусок страницы?

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Update();">Update</a>
<div id="updating">
   тут контент, который должен измениться
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Update() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "урл_скрипта_который_отдаст_нужные_данные",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
          $('#updating').html(data);    
      }
   });
}
```

Не забыть подключить jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Недавно я написал подобный [Ajax модуль под Framework CodeIgniter](http://phh.tj/ajax-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-framework-%D0%B0-codeigniter-update-panel/).

Comment: Я в танке! А как это использовать без CodeIgniter?

Comment: Там же всё под него сделано.

Comment: Если без него, то нужно использовать ajax, это уже немного сложней, придется Вам немного знать Javascript или хотя бы jQuery, можете полистать это http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Если можно, то хоть дайте намёк, как это сделать (jQuery и AJAX я немного владею).